# Gaussian Primes List

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Does anyone have a larger list of the first unique gaussian primes ordered by their norm?
Uniqueness can be achieved if one starts with $p_1=1+i$ and requires that for odd primes $p_i \equiv 1 \mod 2+2i$. The first primes are then
\begin{align}
p_2 &= -1 + 2i \\
p_3 &= -1 - 2i \\
p_4 &= -3  \\
p_5 &=  3 + 2i \\
p_6 &=  3 - 2i \\
p_7 &=  1 + 4i \\
p_8 &=  1 - 4i \\
\vdots
\end{align}

Also: Is there something like a prime-number theorem for gaussian primes?

Comment: Those seem to me to be two rather unrelated questions that you should ask separately.

Comment: "unique" is confusing in this context : $1+4i$ and $1-4i$ have the same norm. In which sense are they unique then ?

Comment: I don't think I want to open a question with just 1 sentence, as people seem to not like it, as they want more context.
@Peter: They are unique in the sense the same way as conventional prime numbers are unique: Every gaussian integer can be decomposed uniquely into gaussian primes.

Comment: @Diger I still do not get what you mean : Unique upto conjugation and units ? If so,  why not just list $1+4i$ ? And why is $4+i$ ruled out ?

Comment: Because $4+i \equiv i \mod 2+2i$ and not $1$. It can be represented by multiplying $1-4i$ with the unit $i$.

Comment: So if $z=a+ib$ with $(a,b) \in {\mathbb Z}^2$ is a gaussian integer then it is uniquely decomposed as $$z=i^k \prod_{n=1}^\infty p_n^{\nu_n}$$ with $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ and only finitely many $\nu_n > 0$.